# Загрузка сайта Yii2 на хостинг

Tags: php, yii2

Возникла такая проблема. При загрузки frontent файлов на сервер, при обработки запроса выводит такую ошибку:

> Error (#8) An internal server error occurred.
>
> The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
>
> Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

Хотя на локальном сервере всё работает правильно. Не могу понять в чем дело. Но есть предположение, что во всем виноват вызов функции контроллера. Их у меня всего две, вынес их в отдельную модель. Ошибка осталась.

Comment: Проблем может быть много.....как пример у вас у файлов пхп начинается с короткого тэга `<?` а сервер не поддерживает это на хосте.......может константа YII_DEBUG в основном файле установлена в true, хотя в на проде должна быть  YII_ENV.........может версия PHP не совпадает....... вообще не плохо заглянуть в логи и посмотреть может там что-то подробнее написано

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А как просмотреть логи?

Comment: /frontend/runtime/logs/app.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все проблемы в yii решаются с помощью 2 волшебных вещей:
включить вывод ошибок
включить debug panel
Что бы вместо An internal server error occurred видеть реальную ошибку и место ее возникновения.
Так же можно посмотреть логи сервера, если эта ошибка произошла до того как запущен yii. Чаще всего при переносе и такой ошибке беда в index.php, потому что пути не верные или не перенеслось часть файлов. Можно закоментить там все и по одному подключать, на каком сдохнет - проверить существование его.

Comment: Да. Вы совершенно правы. Зайдя на "корень сайта"/index.php И убрав там коментирование `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);` я увидел реальную проблему и смог исправить код. Но всё равно спасибо.

Answer (score -2):

Если под ubuntu ставить yii2, то в основном проблемы с правами на папки - это первое что бывает.

```
chmod -vR 0777 assets
```

Comment: Из очереди проверок: выглядит нормально, однако считаю плохим советом и ставлю минус. Подробнее: [почему ставить 077 - плохой совет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528681/213987).